# Parametric bootstrap (Edited)

Tags: bootstrap-sampling

The first question is quite easy, but I'm stuck with the second one. Any suggestion?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0yMz.jpg

Comment: Can you see the image now?

Comment: Continuing internet problems. Giving up for now.